# Avoid or block all load balanced sites from being crawled

Tags: web-crawler, umbraco, load-balancing, robots.txt

We have an Umbraco site in a load balanced environment and we need to make sure only the actual URL gets crawled and not the different production URLs.

We only want `example.com` to be indexed while load balancers at `production1.example.com` and `production2.example.com` are not.

Do I add a disallow rule for those URLs to the robots.txt, or add a meta `nofollow` tag to the head? Or is there another way to have the load balancing URLs not indexed by crawlers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best solution: Don't make node-specific URLs publicly available (we usually use local ip/port to check a site on a specific node).

Since you have those domains, you may serve a different robots.txt depending on the domain (using URL rewriting).

Comment: The client unfortunately wants those URLs publicly available, but I'll give you the answer anyway.